# Java Socket Calculator Subtraction and Multiplication is not working but Addition is working

Tags: java

my code is as the following:
The Problem is that, Subtraction and Multiplication is not working but the addition is working fine... I at least get a result but, the number is completly wrong, so multiplying the 3 numbers results in 232. If I change the operator to subtraction, the result is 231. So I guess it chooses the wrong number to calculate?
What am I doing wrong? Or what is the problem why it is not working? I tried debugging but it did not work for me sadly.

Thank you in advance!

```
Server :
package sample;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class server {


ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(10);

server() throws IOException {
    while ( true ) {
            Socket client = server.accept();
            InputStream input = client.getInputStream () ;
            OutputStream output = client.getOutputStream () ;

            
            int op = input.read();
            
            int num1 = 0;
            int num2 = 0;
            int num3 = 0;
            
            num1 = input.read();
            num2 = input.read();
            num3 = input.read();
            
            switch(op) {
            case 0:
                output.write (num1 + num2 + num3);
                break;
            case 1:
                output.write (num1 - num2 - num3);
                break;
            case 2:
                output.write ((num1 * num2) * num3);
                break;
            }


            output.flush();
            input.close();
            output.close();
    }}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {
        server server = new server() ;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }}}
```

---

```
Client Code:
package sample;


import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {


Client() throws IOException {
    Socket server = new Socket ("localhost", 10);
        InputStream input = server.getInputStream();
        OutputStream output = server.getOutputStream();
        
        output.write(2);
        
        output.write(5);
        output.write(10);
        output.write(20);
        
        output.flush();
        System.out.println(input.read());
        server.close();
        input.close();
        output.close();
        }

public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {
        Client client = new Client();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }}}
```

Comment: What does "socket" have to do with your question?

Comment: maybe you should print/log the data received by the server; and its result (and read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(int)) of `write()`: "*The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored*")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it helps to use the DataInputStream and DataOutputStream classes for writing ints, chars, and Java primitive data types over a stream.

Here is a code example for the server.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);

    Server() throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            Socket client = server.accept();
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));

            int op = input.readInt();
            int num1 = input.readInt();
            int num2 = input.readInt();
            int num3 = input.readInt();

            switch (op) {
                case 0:
                    output.writeInt(num1 + num2 + num3);
                    output.flush();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    output.writeInt(num1 - num2 - num3);
                    output.flush();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    output.writeInt(num1 * num2 * num3);
                    output.flush();
                    break;
            }

            input.close();
            output.close();
            client.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Server server = new Server();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a code example for the client.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {

    Client() throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));

        output.writeInt(1);
        output.writeInt(5);
        output.writeInt(10);
        output.writeInt(20);
        output.flush();

        int response = input.readInt();
        System.out.println(response);

        input.close();
        output.close();
        socket.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Client client = new Client();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can run the server as a background process, and then run the client.

```
% java Server.java &
% java Client.java
-25
```

You can see that the subtraction routine is working fine.

The operation 5-10-20 returns -25.

I think that the DataInputStream and DataOutputStream classes solve a lot of problems that might be happening that are hard to find.

For example, the InputStream.read() method is not able to read negative numbers, because it returns an int in the range 0 to 255.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is
> returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available
> because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is
> returned. This method blocks until input data is available, the end of
> the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.

That's one reason DataInputStream and DataOutputStream make things easier when writing primitives across a stream.

I tested the addition, subtraction, and multiplication routines using the code from the examples.

The code works fine for all three cases. Each routine gives the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

`OutputStream.write(int b)` and `InputStream.read()` send/receive a single byte. A byte can only hold values between 0 and 255, while 5 * 10 * 20 = 1000. You will have to send each value as several bytes.